# Thumbnail Navigator does not display images before start index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am using Jssor Thumbnail Slider in my project.

You can see options below:

```
var ajxSayfa = $('#itSayfa').val();
if(''==ajxSayfa || null==ajxSayfa){
    ajxSayfa = '0';
}

console.log(ajxSayfa);

var jssor_1_options = {
        $StartIndex: ajxSayfa,
        $AutoPlay: 0,
        $Loop:0,
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
        },
        $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
            $Rows: 4,
            $SpacingX: 5 
        },
        $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Rows: 1,
            $Cols: 6,
            $Orientation: 2,
            $AutoCenter: 2,
            $Loop:0,
        }
      };

var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
```

If $StartIndex is different than  0, images before $StartIndex cant be displayed in thumbnail navigator.

Is there a way to see all images in thumbnail navigator even $StartIndex is not 0?

And also i have one more problem with thumbnail navigator. When i navigate between images, thumbnail navigator auto-rotate itself and thumbnail of current image goes top if there are more items than $Cols.

I want to display thumbnail of current image at the mid of thumbnail navigator. Is there an option for this?

This is my second question about Jssor. First one hasnt been replied yet. I hope this question can get any answer.

Many thanks in advance!
 M.

Comment: `$("#id").val()` returns undefined, not null

Comment: thanks for reply. but the problem is not about the value of input. i can check the value with console log and no problem with it. I set StartIndex as $StartIndex: 1, and also i couldnt display first image in thumbnail navigator.

Comment: I have no idea about the library, just saw that issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of thumbnail display with option `$Loop:0` has been fixed.
Please download the latest version.

Also, please set `$Align` to align active thumbnail.
For example

```
$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
    $Cols: 5,
    $SpacingX: 5,
    $SpacingY: 5,
    $Align: 390
  }
```

Images display with no problem if $StartIndex is different than 0.

Open the link below, you can set settings to see how it works.

https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider/=edit

Comment: if i remove $Loop:0 first and last images follow each other in thumbnail navigator. In my case last image should be displayed at the  bottom of the navigator. is there a way to display indexes in thumbnail navigator?

Comment: i removed $Loop:0 and set $StartIndex: 2 and i still cant display first 2 items thumbnail in navigator. Would you like me to share my files with you?

Comment: i just downloaded the newest version(26.0.0) and all works well now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's great news!